# NoSuchElementFoundException While Receiving Data from Server

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public class cli
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int no,rec;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1400);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("Enter any number");
        no = sc.nextInt();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(no);

        rec = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Receive number is " + rec);
    }
}
```

I am sending a number to server and getting a number that is multiple of the number sent, but the problem I am facing is here: the `rec=sc1.nextInt()` statement gives me `NoSuchElementFoundException`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

---

Server code:

```
public class Server {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1400);
  System.out.println("Waiting ");
  Socket s1 = ss.accept();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(s1.getInputStream());
  int a = sc.nextInt();
  int temp = 2 * a;
  PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());
  ps.write(temp);
  ps.flush();
  System.out.println("Got and sent Sucessfull " + temp);
  ss.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure server has received your number and can answer something ? You may need to do some kind of a flush on `ps`.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but it's common practice with Java for class names to begin with an upper case character. Following that convention makes for more readable code.

Comment: I dont understand why this question is upvoted.

Comment: I assume you would have written the server code for this `cli` class. If so, can you post the server code as well?

Comment: public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1400);
System.out.println("Waiting ");
Socket s1=ss.accept();
Scanner sc=new Scanner(s1.getInputStream());
int a=sc.nextInt();
int temp=2*a;
PrintWriter ps=new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());
    ps.write(temp);
    ps.flush();
    System.out.println("Got and sent Sucessfull   "+temp);
   ss.close();
    }
}

Comment: @Gaël i want to know why the number sended by server is not geeting the client and throwing nusuchelementfound exception

Comment: @user3054158 : you can edit your post to add more info instead of adding a comment which is not readable at all ;)

Comment: So you have logs on server side, what are you seeing ? "Got and send successfull" or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not writing a number to the server's output, but a character with the 2*a code.

```
int temp = 2 * a;
PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());
ps.write(temp);
```

Here invoking [`write(temp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write%28int%29) writes the character with the `temp` code to the output. For example, if `a` was 16, then `temp` is 32, so writing this to the `PrintWriter` actually writes a space character. If you want to write the number as a string, do this:

```
ps.write(Integer.toString(temp));
```

Comment: this would be helpfull...Thankx !!